# Which electrical portable fluid pumping actuators that aren't based on electric motors, combustion engines, or piezoelectric actuators?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, hydraulics, actuator

So, basically, I'm trying to find a practical, electrical, portable and efficient alternative for hydraulic pumps that doens't use electric motors, combustion engines or piezoelectric actuators.

The first thing I tried was to ask ChatGPT and BingGPT, but as you can guess, they didn't help much.

I found, electro-thermal actuators like Shape Memory Alloys and Wax motors, besides solenoid pumps, these all have their own pros and cons (SMA's have efficiencies below 10%, I couldn't find the value for wax motors and solenoids are really heavy), but I'm still trying to find other alternatives.

[image: Shape Memory Alloy Pump]
[image: Solenoid pump]
[image: Wax motor]

Comment: Check out the hydraulic ram pump.

Comment: @SolarMike I forgot to say " portable actuator", hydraulic ram pumps can only work in very specific situation

Comment: You haven't specified any preferred source of power.

Comment: @SimonB Fixed it.

Comment: When you "forget" crucial information we base our replies on what you do say.

Comment: So those ones with batteries - included or excluded as they may drive an electric motor...

Comment: If you're looking for a portable alternative that matches the performance of the ones listed, it doesn't exist because if it did, it would be a lot more common.

Comment: An electric motor could be any device that turns electricity into motion.  While it commonly refers to rotary devices, the internal workings of those are not that different from the more simplistic solenoids.  Act of pumping requires flow also known as motion. If you want electrical devices that produce motion, excluding all electrical devices that produce motion... Your phrasing may instead be clearer to exclude things that spin or things that use magnetic fields or something a bit more specific.